# Format value as currency in HTML table

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have the HTML table shown below that displays a variable which is set by an array.

How can set the values as a currency to display correctly in the relevant table cell?

Here is my code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("exvat");x.innerHTML=data[14][1];
var y = document.getElementById("incvat");y.innerHTML=data[15][1];


<div class="card bg-light mb-3">
<div class="card-header">Pricing Data</div>
<div class="card-body">
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr> 
<th></th> 
<th></th> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>Price Ex Vat</td> 
<td id="exvat"></td>
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>Price Inc Vat</td> 
<td id="incvat"></td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: The code isn't complete. It's not clear how is [tag:google-apps-script] related to this question and it's very likely that [tag:javascript] should be added. Refs. [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a fixed currency, then you could simply do something like:

```
var x = document.getElementById("exvat");x.innerHTML= "USD$" + data[14][1];

var y = document.getElementById("incvat");y.innerHTML= "USD$" + data[15][1];
```

Of course, change "USD$" to the currency you would like. It's a String concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trial and error, the following worked

Rik

```
var x = document.getElementById("exvat");x.innerHTML=data[14][1].toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });
```